# Why does io.Copy sometimes lose lines when reading from a socket?

Tags: sockets, go

Please help me understand the observed behavior of reading from a socket.

In the experiment, the sender always sends the same lines, which end in '\n', then closes the write end of a socket.

This code on a receiving side works as expected, printing each line:

```golang
    rdr := bufio.NewReader(sock)
    for {
        b, err := rdr.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Print(string(b))
    }
```

However, this code

```golang
n, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, sock)
```

sometimes skips a random number of lines from the beginning of the data block, and only prints the rest (`n` changes accordingly, and `err` is always nil).

The `sock` is a custom type, which abstracts `net.TCPConn` and `tls.Conn`, which is otherwise used throughout the codebase w/o problems.

Why lines at the beginning of the read by `io.Copy` are sometimes lost?

Comment: Do you read from `sock` prior to using `io.Copy()`? E.g. `bufio.Reader` is a buffered reader, it might read and buffer more from its source than what you've read from it.

Comment: You are right! The `bufio.Reader` is used prior to this code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bufio.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Reader) implements buffering for an [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) object. What does this mean? If you use a `bufio.Reader` to read from an `io.Reader` source, it may read more data from its source (and buffer it) than what you read directly from the `bufio.Reader` itself.

This means if you use a `bufio.Reader` to read from the `sock` first, and then you use [`io.Copy()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy), there may be some data already read from `sock` and sitting in the `bufio.Reader`'s internal buffer, which `io.Copy()` will not see and will not copy.

You shouldn't mix those 2 on the same `io.Reader` source. If you must, then be sure to first drain the `bufio.Reader`'s buffer, then proceed to copy from `sock` like this:

```
// First drain the buffer:
n, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, rdr)
// Handle error

// Then proceed with the socket:
n, err = io.Copy(os.Stdout, sock)
// Handle error
```

Comment: I ended up consuming `bufio.Buffered()` data from the `bufio.Reader`, and then proceed with the normal `io.Copy`